# Can't start VS Code with Uncaught Exception

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: app.setVersion is not a function
at Object.<anonymous>(C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\atom.asar\browser\lib\init.js:81:9)
at Object.<anonymous>(C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\atom.asar\browser\lib\init.js:106:4)
at Module._compile(module.js:418:26)
at Object.Module._extension..js(module.js:436:10)
at Module.load(module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load(module.js:298:12)
at Function.Module.runMain(module.js:459:10)
at startup (node.js:131:18)
at node.js:879:3
```

I have tried many version of node.js. What can I try next?

Comment: can you post the code you are trying to run

Comment: No code. When I try to start vscode, vscode give me those message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. In some situation (I don't know), VS Code will write incorrect environment variable. So I have to fix it manually. Then VS Code works.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't exchange the node.js version VSCode is running with. The [installer](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/?dv=win) brings everything you need. 
The installation seems to be broken.

- Uninstall Visual Studio Code
- Delete the folder `%USERPROFILE\.vscode%` when it exists.
- Reinstall VSCode

In case it is still failing then [file a bug](https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I just downloaded and installed a new version and issue was resolved.
I did not delete the program files. Still using previous extensions and settings.